# Programa com problema pra compilar

Tags: compilação, syntax-error, fortran

Criei esse programa para calcular o IMC, porém ele não executa por completo.
Ele pede para entrar com o peso e a altura, mas não retorna nenhum resultado.

Alguém poderia me dizer o que está errado?

```
PROGRAM Calc
 IMPLICIT NONE
 REAL :: peso, altura, mmc
 write(*,*) "Valor do peso = ? "
 read(*,*) peso
 write(*,*) "Valor do altura = ? "
 read(*,*) altura
 mmc = (peso/altura)
 write (*,*) mmc
 STOP
END PROGRAM Calc
```

Comment: Após eu digitar os 2 valores de entrada, ele não printa o resultado na tela, simplesmente fecha o terminal

Comment: Qual linguagem e compilador está usando ?

Comment: Force 2.0 Fortran 90

Answer (score 2):

Simplesmente adicione um novo READ no final para que ele espere o pressionamento de uma tecla antes de encerrar o código.

Comment: outra alternativa é rodar o programa pelo terminal, não por uma IDE. (: